# Java JInternalFrame not refreshing and returning an error

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Dear Friends of Stackoverflow,

I kindly ask for your help as I'm stuck with the programming of a small interface:

**here's what I'm trying to do**: 
I have a JDesktopPane with a few internal Frames. The logic is: 
- the DesktopPane starts with a Launch Window (a JInternalFrame) that has the button for level 1
- The user clicks on Level 1 and a new JInternal Window Level 1 opens (launch window closes) with a button
- the user clicks the button and sets level 1 to complete
- The JInternal Window Level 1 Closes
- the launch window re-opens but, as Level 1 has been set to completed, now the Launch window has a new button to access level 2
- the user clicks on that button and access level 2 and so on

**here's what happens**
- I start the program, I get the launch window with button for level 1
- I click on the button and I go back to the launch window
BUT
- there is no button for level 2
- furthermore: if I click again on button level 1 I get an error

**Here my code**: I hope somebody can point me in the right direction
**MAIN CLASS**

```
package gioco;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame; 
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class AllInAWindow extends JFrame {
//create components outside constructor    
JDesktopPane MainDesktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
JInternalFrame IFrameLaunchWindow = new JInternalFrame(); 
JInternalFrame IFrameLevel1 = new JInternalFrame(); 
JInternalFrame IFrameLevel2 = new JInternalFrame();


//let's create the constructor    
public AllInAWindow() {
    initUI(); 
}
public void initUI(){

    VariablesSetEGet VariablesSetEGetObj = new VariablesSetEGet(); 
    //-------------------------IFrame Level1--------------------------//        
    //interface of IFrame Level1
    IFrameLevel1.setTitle("Level 1");
    IFrameLevel1.setSize(200, 200);
    IFrameLevel1.setLocation(200, 200);
    IFrameLevel1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
    JButton action1L1 = new JButton("action 1 Level1");
    action1L1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5 ,5, 5, 5));
    IFrameLevel1.add(action1L1);
    //button action
    roundLevelAction1 roundLevelAction1Obj = new roundLevelAction1(); //create object of the constructor                  
    action1L1.addActionListener(roundLevelAction1Obj);//add listener to JButton and pass it through the constructor

    //-------------------------IFrame Level2--------------------------//        
    //interface of IFrame Level2
    IFrameLevel2.setTitle("Level 2");
    IFrameLevel2.setSize(200, 200);
    IFrameLevel2.setLocation(300, 300);        
    IFrameLevel2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
    JButton action1L2 = new JButton("action 1 Level2");
    action1L2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5 ,5, 5, 5));
    IFrameLevel2.add(action1L2);
    //button action
    roundLevelAction2 roundLevelAction2Obj = new roundLevelAction2(); //create object of the constructor                  
    action1L2.addActionListener(roundLevelAction2Obj);//add listener to JButton and pass it through the constructor

    //-------------------------iFrame Launch window-----------------------------//
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setLayout(null);
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setTitle("INIZIO");
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setClosable(true);
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setSize(400, 400);                
    //button level 1
    JButton ButtonLevel1 = new JButton("level1"); //create the button variable
    ButtonLevel1.setSize(200, 40);
    ButtonLevel1.setLocation(100, 120);
    ButtonLevel1.addActionListener//add the listener so that the button can launch the window with the board level
    (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent lanciaLevel1) //create the action
            {                    
                MainDesktopPane.add(IFrameLevel1); //launch the frame with the level 1
                IFrameLevel1.setVisible(true); //set it to visible
                IFrameLaunchWindow.dispose();//close this launch window                     
            }
        }
    );
    IFrameLaunchWindow.add(ButtonLevel1); //add the button of the level 1
    ButtonLevel1.setVisible(true);
    //button level 2
    JButton ButtonLevel2 = new JButton("level2"); 
    ButtonLevel2.setSize(200, 40);
    ButtonLevel2.setLocation(100, 180);
    ButtonLevel2.addActionListener
    (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent lanciaLevel2)
            {                                             
                MainDesktopPane.add(IFrameLevel2); //launch the frame with the level 2
                IFrameLevel1.setVisible(true); //set it to visible
                IFrameLaunchWindow.dispose();//close this launch window                     
            }
        }
    );
    //same as before but here the if: if level1 is not set to completed the button for level2 won't appear
    if (VariablesSetEGetObj.getL1()==1){
        IFrameLaunchWindow.add(ButtonLevel2);  
        ButtonLevel2.setVisible(true);
    }        
    //button level 3 (just for image, same logic)
    JButton ButtonLevel3 = new JButton("level3"); 
    ButtonLevel3.setSize(200, 40);
    ButtonLevel3.setLocation(100, 240);
    if (VariablesSetEGetObj.getL2()==1){
        IFrameLaunchWindow.add(ButtonLevel3);  
        ButtonLevel3.setVisible(true);
    }        

    MainDesktopPane.add(IFrameLaunchWindow); //start the main panel with the launch window
    IFrameLaunchWindow.setVisible(true);
    add(MainDesktopPane);//add the main desktopPane to the Frme                
}

class roundLevelAction1 implements ActionListener {//action of the button in IFrame 1
    public roundLevelAction1(){
            //there are graphical elements here in the original code but not relevant for this
    }         
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ActionLevel1) {//if button is clicked
            VariablesSetEGet VariablesSetEGetObj = new VariablesSetEGet(); 
            VariablesSetEGetObj.setL1(1);//set Level 1 to complete 
            IFrameLevel1.dispose(); //close L1 window
            //go back to launch window but now it should show button to access L2 as L1 has been set to completed
            MainDesktopPane.add(IFrameLaunchWindow); 
            IFrameLaunchWindow.setVisible(true);

        }
}

class roundLevelAction2 implements ActionListener {//action of button in IFrame2
    public roundLevelAction2(){
            //there are graphical elements here in the original code but not relevant for this
    }         
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ActionLevel2) {//if button is clicked
            VariablesSetEGet VariablesSetEGetObj = new VariablesSetEGet(); 
            VariablesSetEGetObj.setL2(1);//set level 2 to complete
            IFrameLevel2.dispose(); //close L2 window
            //go back to launch window but now it should show button to access L3 as L2 has been set to completed
            MainDesktopPane.add(IFrameLaunchWindow); 
            IFrameLaunchWindow.setVisible(true);                
        }
}


public static void main (String[]args) {
    //as this will launch the "fresh" new game, we set each level (and therefore button) 
    //to disabled except button 1. we do it here outside the runnable
    VariablesSetEGet VariablesSetEGetObj = new VariablesSetEGet(); 
    VariablesSetEGetObj.setL1(0);
    VariablesSetEGetObj.setL2(0);
    //TRIGGER LAUNCH WINDOW (see ZCode1)
    EventQueue.invokeLater
    (new Runnable() 
        { 
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                AllInAWindow AllInAWindowObj = new AllInAWindow(); 
                AllInAWindowObj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                AllInAWindowObj.setVisible(true);
                AllInAWindowObj.setSize(800, 800);
            }
        }   
    );
}
}
```

**SEPARATE CLASS**

```
public class VariablesSetEGet {
static int L1 = 0; 
public void setL1 (int L1){
    this.L1 = L1; 
}
public int getL1 (){
    return L1; 
}
static int L2 = 0; 
public void setL2 (int L2){
    this.L2 = L2; 
}
public int getL2 (){
    return L2; 
}    
}
```

many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: as an integration of the post I would like to specify that I already tried to insert in the actionEvents that call the LaunchWindow repaint() and revalidate() and this did not solve

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` instead of `JInternalFrame`s. [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Use some kind of controller that knows or can determine the current state and control where the user can move to

Comment: This - `IFrameLaunchWindow.setLayout(null);` - isn't going to help

Comment: When do you add the "second level" button to the `IFrameLaunchWindow`? Also, you might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: You do realise that `VariablesSetEGet VariablesSetEGetObj = new VariablesSetEGet();` isn't actually doing anything, each time you do this, you make a local copy of `VariablesSetEGet` which, when the method exists, goes out of context and is lost...

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, thank you for taking the time to answer. To your questions: 1) I will definitely look at the CardLayout, thanks a mil for the suggestion. 2) so U think that the Layout Manager (setlayout(null)) is the one preventing the code to be inserted?

Comment: 3) as for "when I add the second level button: I add it but conditioned by an if:     `if (VariablesSetEGetObj.getL1()==1){
        IFrameLaunchWindow.add(ButtonLevel2);  
        ButtonLevel2.setVisible(true);
    }`

Comment: 4) my apologies: I thought I was applying most of the code conventions but I'll read them again. 5) and as for the local copy of the object doing nothing thanks a mil for pointing it out: I put together several classes that were separated so I may have done that incorrectly

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer: I read the CardLayout but it doesn't help me. You see, the issue is not that the LaunchWindow doesn't work: if I change, in the "main", the VariablesSetEGetObj.setL1(from 0 to 1);        VariablesSetEGetObj.setL2(from 0 to 1); when you set them to 1 you can see all the 3 buttons in the launchwindow, and the button 2 launches the level 2 (correctly!). So it's not a layout problem. The problem is that the L1 variable is set to 1 but the LaunchWindow, when it's launched again, doesn't see that

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  You are using the `JInternaFrame` to switch views, this is what `CardLayout` is designed to do.  If you were to use some kind of controller to manage the navigation, it could be updating your "launch" view based on the current state of your "SetEGet" class.  It's not the responsibility of the other "views" to physically change the state of the launch view.

Comment: Using a `null` layout is a contributing factor. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: *"The problem is that the L1 variable is set to 1 but the LaunchWindow, when it's launched again, doesn't see that"* - As I stated, you are creating local instances of your `VariablesSetEGetObj` class, which means that the `LaunchWindow` has no means by which it can see any changes occurring.  This could be helped through the use of some kind of controller...

Comment: @Madprogrammer: thank you for clarifying and for your suggestion. I will change the logic using a cardLayout. If you want to move this in a formalized answer I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not THE solution to the initial problem: this is a change of logic based on the suggestion of MadProgrammer, which was to **abandon the JInternalFrame and use CardLayout**. And doing my research on CardLayout I managed to do what I wanted to initially do . **Here the code**

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CLayout {
    //1) create the Frame
    JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame("Finestra di Gioco"); 
    //2) create as many JPanels as messages + levels, but...
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel(); //...the first one needs to contain them all
    JPanel FinestraLancio = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel Livello1 = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel Livello2 = new JPanel(); 
    //3) create the buttons to switch among panels
    JButton OpenLevel1 = new JButton("Open Level 1"); 
    JButton CompleteLevel1 = new JButton("Complete Level 1"); 
    JButton OpenLevel2 = new JButton("Open Level 2"); 
    JButton CompleteLevel2 = new JButton("Complete Level 2"); 

    //4) create an instance of the card Layout method
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout(); 

    //5) create the constructor
    public CLayout(){
        //5.a) assign the instance of the card Layout to the container panel
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);

        //5.b) create the windows insert the buttons, assign the actions
        FinestraLancio.add(OpenLevel1); 
        FinestraLancio.add(OpenLevel2);
        OpenLevel2.setVisible(false);
        Livello1.add(CompleteLevel1); 
        Livello2.add(CompleteLevel2); 

        Livello1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        Livello2.setBackground(Color.blue);

        OpenLevel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent OpenLevel1){
                cl.show(panelCont, "2"); //this "2" is the position indicator, 
                                        //we'll discuss it at 5c
            }
        });

        OpenLevel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent OpenLevel2){
                cl.show(panelCont, "3");
            }
        });

        CompleteLevel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent CompleteLevel1){
                OpenLevel2.setVisible(true);
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });
        CompleteLevel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent CompleteLevel2){
                OpenLevel2.setVisible(false);
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });        
        //5.c) now put the elements in the container panel, and add the name of 
        //the element and the position indicator you will need that position 
        //indicator when you want to call that specific window
        panelCont.add(FinestraLancio, "1"); //"1" is the position indicator
        panelCont.add(Livello1, "2"); 
        panelCont.add(Livello2, "3"); 

        //now indicate that the instance of the cardlayout has the container as 
        //its main panel and inside the container the first panel to be displayed 
        //is the one with the position indicator "1", i.e. the LaunchWindow
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        //create the main window
        MainWindow.add(panelCont); 
        MainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        MainWindow.setSize(400, 400);
        MainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater
        (new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new CLayout(); 
            }
        }); 
    }

}
```